# Drupal Ubercart 2checkout, what DIRECT RETURN option to choose?

Tags: drupal, return, ubercart, 2checkout

About    "Direct Return"   it is written here to choose     "Header Redirect"
(3. Under Direct Return select Header Redirect.)
https://www.2checkout.com/shopping-cart/ubercart/

But it is written here to choose    "Given links back to my website"
(3. Under Direct Return select Given links back to my website.)
http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/31330/configure_2checkout_payment_ubercart_drupal_6

Do you know if given links back to my website is definitively the option to select?

More info about   "How Does The Return Process Work?"
2checkout.com/blog/knowledge-base/merchants/tech-support/passbacks-and-returns/how-does-the-return-process-work/?plain

Answer (score 0):

The return method depends on the version of the extension you are using. If you are using the version found at https://github.com/craigchristenson/ubercart-3-2checkout you use Header Redirect. The 2Checkout extension that is included in the Ubercart core uses Given Links back to my Website. Unfortunately the return function in the 2Checkout module that is included with UberCart has a bug and will not be fixed until the next release. In the mean time I suggest using the extension referenced at the URL above. If you have any trouble with your integration, you can contact 2Checkout directly for integration assistance.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this version, I will try it now and select Header Redirect.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried it, but it seems that the 2checkout module found at the address you gave me is for DRUPAL 7, but I am using Drupal 6. Does it mean that there is no 2checkout working module for Drupal 6 and Ubercart 2 ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok I think that I have found:

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think that I have found the solution here:

http://www.ubercart.org/project_issue/access_denied_2checkout_order_completion

## 1

The problem does not appear to be related to SSL. Their is an error in the ubercart 2Checkout return script that is causing this return issue. Ubercart is trying to verify the MD5 hash that is being passed back using a hash of secret word, vendor number, merchant_order_id, total which is incorrect and causing the validation to fail. To correct the issue please open the following file "drupal/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_2checkout/uc_2checkout.pages.inc" and edit line 20 so that it matches the following:

$valid = md5(variable_get('uc_2checkout_secret_word', 'tango') . $_POST['sid'] . $_POST['order_number'] . $_POST['total']);

So it really mean that there is no good 2checkout module for Ubercart and that the only solution is to hack line #20  ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubercart has these issues addressed in the dev branches of UberCart 2 and 3. You can also get just the fixed 2Checkout modules at the URLs below:

**UberCart-2 Drupal-6**
https://github.com/craigchristenson/ubercart-2-2checkout

**UberCart3 Drupal-7**
https://github.com/craigchristenson/ubercart-3-2checkout